# SDL_Addtimer works inconsistent or not at all

Tags: c++, sdl

I recently started working with SDL and I encountered a problem

each time  I do SDL_Addtimer it works very inconsistent or not at all

so far the only time I got it to work is if I put it in an infinity loop and hope it doesn't crash.

```
enter codUint32 callback( Uint32 interval, void *p){
printf("something");
return 0;}



int main (){
bool quit= false;
SDL_TimerID timer;
timer = SDL_AddTimer (6000 , callback , NULL);
while(!quit){
    //to keep the programm running
}
return 0;
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You haven't initialised SDL (e.g. `SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_TIMER);`), and your program have to be still alive when timer triggers. Once your `main` finishes - there is no reason anything will just keep going.

Can't understand your "hope it doesn't crash" - there is no reason why empty loop would crash.

Answer (score -1):

The callback function (..) should return the next timer interval. If the value returned from the callback is 0, the timer is canceled.

Also as mentioned previously  SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_TIMER); is missing.